# Matching position of same elements in two lists

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request

Suppose I have two lists of the same size as follows:

```
A1 = {a, b, c, d};
A2 = {c, a, b, d};
```

I want to construct a function that gives the relation between positions of same elements in both lists.

For example, we see that

```
a = A1[[1]] = A2[[2]]
b = A1[[2]] = A2[[3]]
```

and so on.

With `DeleteCases` and using `Alternatives`, I can tell whether the two elements of two lists are the same or not, but I can not tell which position of them are in the same.

Is there any smart way to find out their relations? In the above example, I want the code to return a list:

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 4}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**

[Ben Izd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/77079/ben-izd) (in a comment) has suggested the following neat modification:
Use [`Catenate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catenate.html) rather than [`Identity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Identity.html) to avoid mapping [`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html)

```
Merge[PositionIndex/@{A1,A2},Catenate]

(* <|a -> {1, 2}, b -> {2, 3}, c -> {3, 1}, d -> {4, 4}|> *)
```

**Original Answer**

```
Merge[{PositionIndex[A1],PositionIndex[A2]},Identity]

(* <|a -> {{1}, {2}}, b -> {{2}, {3}}, c -> {{3}, {1}}, d -> {{4}, {4}}|> *)
```

Or:

```
Map[Flatten,Merge[{PositionIndex[A1],PositionIndex[A2]},Identity]]

%//Values

(* 
  <|a -> {1, 2}, b -> {2, 3}, c -> {3, 1}, d -> {4, 4}|>

  {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 4}} 
*)
```

Comment: (+1) You can replace `Identity` with `Catenate` to skip mapping `Flatten`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Ordering`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html)

```
ar1 = {a, b, c, d}
ar2 = {c, a, b, d}

Thread[Ordering /@ {ar1, ar2}]
```

yields: {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 4}}

Answer (score 4):

**Using `DistanceMatrix`**:

```
Position[DistanceMatrix[A1, A2], 0]
```

**Using `Position`:**

```
Transpose@{Range@Length@A1, Flatten[Position[A2, #] & /@ A1]}
```

**Using `OrderingBy`:**

```
MapIndexed[{First@#2, #1} &, OrderingBy[A2, Position[A1, #] &]]
```

---

*Result*

> {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 4}}

Answer (score 4):

Using `Permutation`:

```
Transpose@{Range[Length[A1]], 
  PermutationList[FindPermutation[A1, A2], Length[A1]]}

(* Out: {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 4}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `Query` and `Dataset`:

```
Query[Merge[#, Flatten] & /* Dataset, PositionIndex][{A1, A2}]
```

[image]

Add Headers with subquery:

```
ds =
 Query[Merge[#, Flatten] & /*
       Query[All, AssociationThread[{"A1", "A2"} -> #] &] @ # & /* Dataset,
   PositionIndex][{A1, A2}]
```

[image]

Now, for example:

```
ds[{Key @ a, Key @ d}, "A2"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One possible way

```
A1={a,b,c,d};
A2={c,a,b,d};

MapIndexed[{First[#2], Flatten@Position[A2, #1]} &, A1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you only want the first position that match, add `First`

```
 MapIndexed[{First[#2],First@Flatten@Position[A2,#1]}&,A1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `GroupBy`:

```
Values@Merge[Keys@GroupBy[{A1, A2}, PositionIndex], Join @@ # &]

(*{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 4}}*)
```